# Javascript - delete object from JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I would like to delete an object from a JSON objects array.
Here is the array:

```
var standardRatingArray = [
    { "Q": "Meal",
      "type": "stars"
    },
    { "Q": "Drinks",
      "type": "stars"
    },
    { "Q": "Cleanliness",
      "type": "stars"
    }
];
```

For example how can I delete the object whose key is `"Q": "Drinks"` ?
Preferably of course without iterating the array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without iterating the array? The only way is to know the index of the object in the array before hand and then use [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) on that item

Comment: @PatrickEvans I agree that you'll need the index beforehand to avoid iteration, but using the delete operator will leave a "hole" in the array (and the arrays length won't change). Probably better to use `.splice` to remove it.

Comment: Just FYI JSON stands for Javascript Object Notation. Which is a way to store a javascript object as a string. Your example is a plain array containing objects, not JSON.

Comment: @CRice, you are correct, i was mistaken and read the question wrong thinking they were wanting to delete the property not the array item

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to find the index of the item to remove, so you'll always have to iterate the array, at least partially. In ES6, I would do it like this:

```js
const standardRatingArray = [
    { "Q": "Meal",
      "type": "stars"
    },
    { "Q": "Drinks",
      "type": "stars"
    },
    { "Q": "Cleanliness",
      "type": "stars"
    }
];

const index = standardRatingArray.findIndex(x => x.Q === "Drinks");

if (index !== undefined) standardRatingArray.splice(index, 1);

console.log("After removal:", standardRatingArray);
```